# How can I have "instance affinity" per source IP in Azure Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I want to set up my custom .NET implementation of a FTP service on Service Fabric and configure the TCP ports of my public endpoint so that when the user is sending data on the different ports of my public endpoint, it is internally directed to the same instance of my service in Service Fabric.

For example if I have two instances A and B, the user connects to the FTP service on the instance A, every data connection created for the service would be directed to the instance A.

The Azure Load Balancer offers the possibility to either:

- [change the distribution mode from hash-based to source IP affinity mode](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-distribution-mode/)
- [in a Cloud Service, we can redirect a public port to a specific port for each VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-multivip/), so I can redirect all traffic to a public port (for example 10000) to the private port 10000 of the instance A

Nevertheless it seems that we do not access to the Azure Service Fabric VMs via Azure Powershell, so I cannot use these solutions.

Is there another way to be able to set these configurations for an Azure Service Fabric cluster, or another way to get this affinity per instance?

Comment: Instances may move around in your cluster, because of balancing and/or node failures. You shouldn't rely on node IP addresses to target a service. Have you considered using a datastore that is tied to the user, instead of a service instance tied to the user?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this probably will help:

In Azure Portal:

Your SF Load Balancer -> Load Balancing Rules -> Your rule for application -> Session Persistence